# How to recover from this kind of startup error without reinstalling Mathematica?

Tags: warning-messages, crash, kernel-startup

[image]

How to recover from this kind of startup error without reinstalling Mathematica?

Comment: The instructions say "Contact technical support ... for more information".  Have you tried that?

Comment: I don't contact them. I don't have a service package plus, I tried in the past and the turnaround time is just too long for me. If I can't figure out by end of day, I'll just reinstall.

Comment: Before reinstall, try deleting the folder `/Users/<usrname>/Library/Mathematica` and open Mathematica.  If that doesn't work, then reinstall.